# Have you used any databases only hosting service?

Tags: mysql, hosting

Are there any database only hosting services?

I need a MySQL only hosting service but I couldn't find any. All mysql hostings are part of a package e.g. PHP + MySQL.

I need it for development purposes. Having my PHP files somewhere else I can remotely connect to this mysql server and once an application is ready I can put that on a server having both PHP + MYsql. [well, there a some reason to have this kinda setup, if you have something to suggest please do.]

Any suggestion/recommendation if you have used any.

Thanks

Comment: Good question, but bad practice!

Comment: I imagine that these are few and far between. Most people who want the database hosted will also want the site itself hosted. Using separate hosts for these makes your site dependent on *two* hosts being up and running instead of one, so it makes sense to use the same host for both just to cut out a point of failure.

Comment: The only bad practice I can relate it to is of security .. what are others??

Comment: Your PHP should really be on the same server (or server farm) as your database if at all possible. Security is enough of an issue to warrant the change alone. It's also unnecessary given that MySQL is free and can be installed on whatever computer you have running the PHP. Could you explain the scenario that requires a development server to not have MySQL?

Comment: @Paulo - scenario is that multiple developers working on same project on their local machines, having source code sync from svn server and "this" remote database server for database.

Comment: @Paulo, incorrect! A database server should be on a different, dedicated server to get the best performance. But it should also be available through an internal network only, so the database server cannot have any Internet access. A popular setup is a hardware router which does port forwarding to the web server, with the database on a different server. The router would control communications with the outside world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you can find hosts with MySQL and PHP cheap enough that it would be easiest for you just to use one of those hosts and only use what you need.

[Web Hosting Buzz](http://www.webhostingbuzz.com/web-hosting.php) has a plan for $5.95 (a month) which has unlimited databases, 400GB storage, and 500GB/Month data transfer.

Comment: well.. then I'll paying for the stuff which I dont use.

Comment: true, but you can find a host for under $10 so i dont think you would save much if it was just MySQL

Comment: < $10 .. how many databases you get on those? I need something which offers, say, unlimited.

Comment: I use Web Hosting Buzz which for 5.95 has 400GB and unlimited databases. http://www.webhostingbuzz.com/web-hosting.php

Comment: and they have good up time. In the last 2 years there was only one time that my server was down. And they had it back up within an hour.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with a database-only host would be the security. The database need to be accessed over the Internet, thus username and password to access it are sent over the Internet. Even though you could add encryption and other protection, there's still a risk that the security is breached.

In general, you should **never** allow direct access to databases over the Internet! It's a real bad practice, which also explains why it's hard to find.

One way to get around such limitation is by building a web service around your database. In this web service you'll add all the functionality that you need to apply on this database, and the web service itself will keep the database itself protected. There would still be a risk that your web service gets compromised but even in that case, the attacker could never do more damage than the specific web service allows.

Such a web service can be created in PHP, although I myself have more experience with doing something similar with .NET and C# on SQL Server...

Comment: Security is a good point. If you can point me more toward web services around database that'll be great. cheers for answering.

Comment: The web service would be something you would have to write yourself, around your database model. Which you can do when the database host also provided PHP. ;-)

Comment: Just checked your comment to @Paulo regarding accessing a dedicated database server and "The router would control communications with the outside world." This means I have to setup my own server to do this?

Comment: @Wbdlvpr, If you use a hosted service, this would be set up by your webhost and they will provide you the means to connect to the database. The router/double server setup is mostly for those who keep their hosting in-house.

Answer (score 3):

A few weeks after the question was posted, Amazon announced a beta of "Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS)." It acts like MySQL 5.1.

http://aws.amazon.com/rds/

Seems pricey for what you want, but you never said *you* were the one who would be paying the bill.

Answer (score 0):

1. Contract a dedicated server.
2. Use it only to host your MySQL database

If the server is managed, they should help you with basic MySQL problems as it is usually preinstalled. I use http://www.hostingmatters.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are just needing this for developement purposes for PHP + MySQL why not just install EasyPHP (http://www.easyphp.org/). This installs quickly and easily and I think it's great for developement.

I've had no problems installing additional PEAR extensions and such after the fact with this.

Comment: Typically we don't need to share database instances until we put everything together. Or do you mean - you modify some code and then he modifies some of the code in the same files?

I've typically had server space for joint developement but the few times I did not have this - we used a database file to maintain concurrency (any table additions, schema updates were made in a script file which was run against our database when we pulled new/merged code to our developement environments)

Answer (score 0):

There's a free option on Heroku and paid options up from there: https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb

Answer (score 0):

You can try freemysqlhosting. 
http://freemysqlhosting.net/